# Perl split by regexp issue

Tags: regex, perl, split

I'm writing some parser on Perl and here is a problem with split. Here is my code:

```
my $str = 'a,b,"c,d",e';
my @arr = split(/,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/, $str);
# try to split the string by comma delimiter, but only if comma is followed by the even or zero number of quotes 

foreach my $val (@arr) {
    print "$val\n"
}
```

I'm expecting the following:

```
a
b
"c,d"
e
```

But this is what am I really received:

```
a
b,"c,d"
b
"c,d"
"c,d"

e
```

I see my string parts are in array, their indices are 0, 2, 4, 6. But how to avoid these odd `b,"c,d"` and other rest string parts in the resulting array? Is there any error in my regexp delimiter or is there some special `split` options?

Comment: do matching instead of splitting `"[^"]*"|[^,]+`

Comment: You're using _split_ and a fancy regex in Perl and never heard that split creates elements from capture groups ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a non-capturing group:

```
my @arr = split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/, $str);
                      ^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/F1hOLC)

Otherwise, the captured texts are output as part of the resulting array.

See [perldoc reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#The-split-operator):

> If the regex has groupings, then the list produced contains the matched substrings from the groupings as well

Comment: Thanks! I enjoy stackoverflow :)

Comment: I only showed where those "weird" elements come from. Please check Sobrique's answer. If you really work with CSV, it is best to use the existing proven tools to parse delimited text.

Answer (score 4):

What's tripping you up is a feature in `split` in that if you're using a group, and it's set to capture - it returns the captured 'bit' as well.

But rather than using `split` I would suggest the `Text::CSV` module, that already handles quoting for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv    = Text::CSV->new();
my $fields = $csv->getline( \*DATA );

print join "\n", @$fields;

__DATA__
a,b,"c,d",e
```

Prints:

```
a
b
c,d
e
```

My reasoning is fairly simple - you're doing quote matching and may have things like quoted/escaped quotes, etc. mean you're *trying* to do a recursive parse, which is something `regex` simply isn't well suited to doing.

Comment: Why advocate `Text::CSV `, how does it work? Can't simple regex work better? I don't get why you mention recursive parsing, which Perl is very good at.

Comment: I advocate it because it works, and makes the code to parse your thing very simple. Regular expressions are great for splitting a line by a delimiter or finding a pattern to search and replace. But matched delimiters - like quotes, brackets or start/end tags - it's worse at, because that's a recursive problem. You can do it, but you'll find lots of edge cases where it doesn't work. Far better to use a parser that can handle it.

Comment: `perl` can do recursive parsing - `Text::CSV` or `XML::Twig` do it very nicely. `regex` cannot (very well - technically it's possible, but you end up with a very big and hard to understand regex)

Comment: CSV parsing does not involve recursion, it's delimited. And Perl _regex_ can indeed do recursive function calls (I didn't mean Perl itself, which is just a language).

Comment: But what if you've got escaped quotes? What about mismatched quotes within your CSV fields? Or escaped commas. Yes, you can do it - by using an perl's extended form of regex - but you reliably end up with... well, something like the OP - something that's hard to follow what it's actually doing and is difficult to troubleshoot when it doesn't work. _My opinion_ is that if your CSV is simple comma delimited (and you don't have to worry about quotes) `split /,/` is fine. But for more complicated, `Text::CSV` is the most appropriate tool.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with CSV. There are _no_ standards, it's all user defined. That's why modules like that give you options. Escaped quote's ? `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`. Mismatched quotes ? Validate an even composition before parsing. Escaped comma's ? Not outside quotes. Mixed field composition, multiple delimiters, line termination. These all factor in. I would say there is no one module/way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parse_line()` of [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html), if you are not really bounded for regex:

```
use  Text::ParseWords;

my $str = 'a,b,"c,d",e';

my @arr = parse_line(',', 1, $str);

foreach (@arr)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
"c,d"
e
```

Comment: Can you explain how `Text::ParseWords` works, instead of just saying use it?

Comment: @sln : Does linked Perl documentation for `Text::ParseWords` not provide a good explanation?

Comment: Well, it might if I want to see nothing but links when I search for solutions. Eventually finding out it's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Do matching instead of splitting.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $str = 'a,b,"c,d",e';
my @matches = $str =~ /"[^"]*"|[^,]+/g;
foreach my $val (@matches) {
    print "$val\n"
}
```